# Prove that in a bitopological space a $\gamma$-hyperconnected space may not be hyperconnected.

Tags: general-topology

In a bitopological space $(X,T_i,T_j)$ a subset A of X is said to be preopen if $A \subseteq i−int(j−cl(A))$ and $\gamma$-open if $A \cap B$  is preopen for every preopen set B in X. A subset B of a bitopological space X is said to be $\gamma$-dense if $\gamma-cl(B)=X$. A bitopological space is $\gamma$-hyperconnected if every $\gamma$-open set is $\gamma$-dense. A bitopological space is hyperconnected if $j-cl(A) = X$ for any $A \in (X, T_1)$.

Comment: Can you give a definition for "bitopological space"?  Also, the notation $A \subset i$ surely isn't correct, unless $A$ is either empty or the integer $i$.

Comment: Suppose $(X, T_1)$ and $(X, T_2)$ be two topologies. Then the structure $(X, T_1, T_2)$ is called a bitopological space. $A \subseteq i-int(j-cl(A))$ is correct. $j-cl(A)$ means $T_2 ~closure~ of~ (A)$ and $i-int~(j-cl~(A))$ means $T_1 interior~ (T_2 ~closure~ (A))$

Comment: So that's basically a hyphen, rather than a minus sign?  I looked at the Wiki and a couple of papers; didn't see anything like this.  What is the difference between $(A)$ and $A$, if any?  Is "preopen" really asymmetric like that with respect to the indices?

Answer (score 0):

Take $X = \{a, b, c\}$, $T_1 = \{\{a.c\}, \phi, X\}$, $T_2 = \{\{b, c\}, \{a, b\}, \{b\}, \phi, X\}$. Then, clearly it is not hyperconnected. Now, $PO(X) = \{ \{b\}, \{a. b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}, \phi, X\}$, $\gamma O(X) = \{\{b\}, \{a, b\}, \phi, X\}$. From this, it is obvious that it is $\gamma$-hyperconnected.